# Images not showing on Jenkins Extent Report due to JETTY Exception StaticException: Unconsumed content

Tags: selenium, jenkins, centos, jetty, extentreports

I have a Jenkins configured on a CentOS machine, I have a job that builds a java selenium project and outputs an extent report with screenshots attached using HTML Publisher Jenkins plugin.
When opening the report via Jenkins the images appear as broken with a 404 not found error.

I opened the Jetty logs since Jenkins standalone is allocated into a Jetty instance, and it appears the following logs:

```
consumeAll AsyncContentProducer@5b67d321[r=ErrorContent [org.eclipse.jetty.util.StaticException: Unconsumed content],t=ErrorContent [org.eclipse.jetty.util.StaticException: Unconsumed content],i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@4816e6fe{s=HttpChannelState@656c99cb{s=IDLE rs=COMPLETED os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=4,c=true/true,a=IDLE,uri=http://10.10.50.67:8080/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SecOps%20Automation/Reports/extentReport_10-24_11:29/ResultsUrlVoid1833.jpg,age=9}]
org.eclipse.jetty.util.StaticException: Unconsumed content
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContentProducer.consumeAll(AsyncContentProducer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer.consumeAll(BlockingContentProducer.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.consumeAll(HttpInput.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onCompleted(HttpConnection.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Note that the URI uri=http://10.10.50.67:8080/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SecOps%20Automation/Reports/extentReport_10-24_11:29/ResultsUrlVoid1833.jpg
is correct and when I go directly to this path on my CentOs machine the image does exists.

Anyone can help with this?

I have already disabled the Jenkins Content Security Policy to enable all css and content on the html, this should be a configuration issue that I am missing along with Jetty

Answer (score 0):

This "unconsumed content" message is a DEBUG/TRACE message indicating that there has been a violation of the HTTP/1.1 persistent connection rules.

What's happening, according to your stacktrace, is that something on Jenkins is reading from the request body content, but hasn't completely read all of the content, leaving some content in the network buffers.

This violates the persistent connection rules, and results in a closed connection once the exchange has been completed.

This stacktrace has no impact on your ability to download the image, as that's the other half of the exchange that has nothing to do with this stacktrace.

This happens extremely often, hence why it's a DEBUG/TRACE level message.
Your issue is somewhere else.  I would recommend reaching out to the Jenkins community on one of their monitored locations and begin troubleshooting with them.

https://www.jenkins.io/participate/connect/